# Get Post title in span tag

Tags: php, wordpress

i want to get the wordpress title post to a span tag.

i use the code below with the_title() in span tags:

```
<?php echo '<div>
<img src="image.jpg"/>
<h2><span>'.the_title().'</span>
</h2></div>'; ?>
```

but the title is show in a tag P, the result is:

```
<p>TITLE_OF_THE_POST_IS_SHOW_HERE
<div>
<img src="image.jpg"/>
<h2><span></span>
</h2></div>
```

in result, the span tags is empty, how do insert the title in the span tag?

Comment: `get_the_title()`, probably, as per usual with wordpress. `the_foo()` outputs data, `get_the_foo()` returns the data

Comment: thanks, its works ^^ and, how i get the image post url? get_the_thumbnail?

Comment: i get the url image:
$i = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'medium' );
i use: <img src="'.$i[0].'"/>

its works, but is include a br tag in the end. how i elimine the br tag?

Answer (score 0):

I would advice changing this

```
<?php echo '<div>
<img src="image.jpg"/>
<h2><span>'.the_title().'</span>
</h2></div>'; ?>
```

to something like this

```
<div>
  <img src="image.jpg"/>
  <h2>
    <?php the_title( '<span>', '</span>' ); ?>
  </h2>
</div>
```

the php the_title function see documentation [Here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title) accepts parameters so you can define the parent tag `<span>` inside of the wordpress function `the_title()`.

Keep in mind that `the_title` shows the current post title. If you want to get a title from another post you can use `get_the_title( post = 3 )` as Mark B mentioned above.

Comment: Have you uploaded the image to the Media section of Wordpress or did you just created an image folder inside of the projects root? if it's the first option you can find the url by clicking on Media in the admin panel and click on the image. You can see the link on the right. Otherwise you can do something like this: `<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() ?>/path/to/image/folder/image.jpg" />`

Comment: i get the url image: $i = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'medium' ); i use: <img src="'.$i[0].'"/> its works, but is include a br tag in the end. how i elimine the br tag?